# initializing a three level jagged array, get error "a nested array initializer is expected"

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a three-level jagged array.

Here's my code:

```
int[][, ,][,] x = new int[1][, ,][,]{
                new int[1,1,1][,] {
                    new int[7,8]
                }
            };
```

I get this error: `A nested array initializer is expected`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, what do you need such a nasty array for?

Comment: I was just curious to see how complicated arrays can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what an initializer for a `[,,]` looks like. For example:

```
int[,,] arr = {{{1}}};
```

Therefore, what you need is more like:

```
int[][, ,][,] x = new int[1][, ,][,]{
        new int[1,1,1][,] {{{new int[7,8]}}}
    };
```

or even just:

```
int[][, ,][,] x = {
        new int[1,1,1][,] {{{new int[7,8]}}}
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works, but I don't understand why I have to use the extra brackets.

Comment: @user2108462 [because that is what the language says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx). A 2x2 array int-array would be `{ {1,2},{3,4} }`, for example; a 2x2x2 would be `int[, ,] arr = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };`

Comment: Thank you I get it now, everything makes sense.